# "Preliminary Considerations"

Tags: meaning

In my thesis I have a part where I provide all the algorithms which I have developed. I want to introduce this part with a chapter containing the literature review regarding these algorithms, introducing the hardware I have worked with, discussing the input data for the algorithms and some other stuff (see below)...

Do you think I can use **"Preliminary Considerations" as title for this chapter?** I have some doubts due to the alternative meaning of "preliminary" which I would describe as "uncomplete" or "sketchy". Although "Preliminary Considerations" seems to be a proper title, "preliminary" has the taste of "has to be completed in further work".

I hope this makes sense to you.

---

**(Coarse) structure of my thesis:**

```
FRONTMATTER

PART I: Introduction

PART II: Models & Theory

PART III: Algorithms
  Chapter PRELIMINARY CONSIDERATIONS
    Section Literature Review
    Section Related Hardware
    Section Input Data
    Section ...
  Chapter Algo 1
    ...
  Chapter Algo N

BACKMATTER
```

Comment: *Preliminary* literally means "Before the threshold" or "before the first step" (Latin, *pre-, -limina*). I would say it's exactly the right word.

Comment: What is confusing me is that I know "preliminary" also from sentences like "These are just the preliminary results" (see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preliminary). It sometimes has the meaning of the german word "vorläufig" which is absolutely not what I want to say (see translation of "vorläufig" here: http://www.dict.cc/?s=vorl%C3%A4ufig&=DEEN&=)

Comment: By the way: "Pre-Liminary" could also be interpreted as "before the limit" and thus as somehow "immature", couldn't it?

Comment: I might just call it "Background Information".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary Considerations is fine: its normal connotation in this context would be as a contrast to main or primary considerations, and perhaps also to final considerations. Alternatives could be Background Considerations or just Backgroumd.

Answer (score 1):

"Preliminary Considerations" sounds ok to me - it's probably what I would call it. I'm a little surprised by "Literature Review" coming so far into the thesis, though - has the literature got nothing to say about "Models and Theory"? Still, I don't know the subject area of your thesis, so it may be fine.

Comment: Thank you. The literature review is spread over the thesis here; this one mentioned in my question is only regarding alternative algorithms...

Answer (score 0):

[Justice J. Randolph](http://pareonline.net/pdf/v14n13.pdf) of Walden University has suggested there are three purposes for providing a literature review:

1. to prove your knowledge of, and familiarity with, your field of study
2. to craft a publishable document in its own right
3. to identify and explain a research family with which you identify (or, I assume, in case you do not identify with a research family, to identify and explain your new paradigm!)

Keeping these three purposes in mind, I suggest you make your literature review a separate "PART" of your thesis. Only when that is accomplished should you continue your thesis. Here is a suggested alternative to the approach you are currently taking:

FRONTMATTER

PART 1:  Introduction

PART 2:  An Overview of Models and Theory in the Literature

PART 3:  Choice of Hardware and Input Data

PART 4:  Algorithms Used

```
     I. Algorithm Number One [or the name or title of the algorhythm]

    II. Algorithm Number Two

   III. Algorithm Number Three [etc.]
```

BACKMATTER/CONCLUSION [where you modestly admit there is so much more to discover and suggest possible future directions in which the discipline can go to advance the field of study]

Comment: I really appriciate your comprehensive (and a little bit offtopic) answer and I will think about it intensively. However, the structure provided above is only a coarse version which does not reveal the true complexity of the work; it is well thought out already.

Comment: @matheburg: You're welcome, and yeah, sometimes ya never know what non sequiter is going to spring forth from my fingertips. Nevertheless, making your review of the literature a "part" unto itself seemed like a good idea to me. With even more suggestions from other EL&U members, you should be in good stead for wrapping up your thesis. "Where no counsel is, the people fall: but in the multitude of counsellors there is safety" (Proverbs 11:14; cf. 15:22). You see, you just never know what's going to spring forth . . .. Don